# what is min here?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, graphing-functions

[image]

I drew the graph for the three equations given[rough]

what does the min notation over here signify?

Ok thanks i get it now!!
so to find out the integral i need to find the area of the shaded region as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Min for minimum, so choose whichever is the least valued of those three inputs to $f$.

Comment: It means for a particular value of $x$ you take the lowest of the values of the three functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition of $f$ says that for a given value of $x$ the value of $f$ is given by the smallest number among $|x|$,$1-|x|$ and $1/\alpha$ that is what $min$ means. Thus $f$ graph looks like a M. You can write a definition of $f$ piecewise. Then your integral is the sum of the areas of those two trapeses

Comment: to find out the integral they find out the area of the two trapeziums formed. Why is that so?

Comment: oh ho!!! i get it now!! thankss!!